# Text to speech for countdown timer

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech, countdowntimer

I have a controller that displays the timer for my countdown app.

[image: screenshot]

The code to display the timer:

```
String get timerString {
    duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
```

I want to add a TTS to speak whenever the timer goes to "3,2,1". Like a countdown TTS. I tried implementing the TTS in the timerString function, but the duration changes too fast for the TTS to speak.

```
Future _speak(String text) async {
   var result = await flutterTts.speak(text);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not await the `speak()` method. Just trigger it and don't wait it.

Here is a function that counts down.

```
void countdown(FlutterTts tts, int from, Duration delay) async {
  for (var i = from; i > 0; i--) {
    tts.speak(i.toString());
    await Future.delayed(delay);
  }
}
```